# docker exec command with Popen in Python

Tags: python, docker

I'm developing an application in which I interact with docker containers.

I want to execute this command in a **docker exec name_of_container command** fashion:
`command= "/usr/bin/balance -b "+ ip_address + " 5001 " + servers_list`

The idea is to do an **echo** **command** **>>** /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf`

I tried as follows :

`p=subprocess.Popen(['docker','exec','supervisor','echo','command'],
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

but it does not work.

This is the error code:

```
exec: "'/usr/bin/balance -b 195.154.12.1 5001 192.186.13.1' >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf": stat '/usr/bin/balance -b 195.154.12.1 5001 192.186.13.1' >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf: no such file or directory
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  That commands looks like it should successfully run "echo command", but you're not redirecting output to a file inside the container (you're consuming the output in Python, where you could get it with `p.read()`).

Comment: This is th error code :
exec: "'/usr/bin/balance -b 195.154.12.1 5001 192.186.13.1' >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf": stat '/usr/bin/balance -b 195.154.12.1 5001 192.186.13.1' >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf: no such file or directory

Comment: Please post enough so that others can reproduce the problem.  A dockerfile and/or a script that generates the problem should be sufficient.

Comment: I can't tell if it is complaining about the entire quoted string not being a valid file name or `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf` not being a valid file name.  You might check that the latter exists in the container and that the code is appending to the file in the container and not the file in the host.

Comment: Looking at the error code line again, it isn't making much sense.  It seems to suggest you are running the string and redirecting the output of executing the string to /etc/....../supervisord.conf.  However, the post talks about echoing a balance command to be run onto the end of supervisord.conf, not the output of that balance command.

Comment: The problem is resolved, thank's all